# PHP - Callable method not as array

Tags: php, callable

Usually in PHP if you have a method `bar` of a class `Foo` and you'd like to pass it around as a callable, you use something like

```
$foo = new Foo();
$callable = [$foo, 'bar'];
```

The downside of this is that `is_array($callable)` evaluates to `true`.

Is there another feasible way to pass around a class method as a callable such that `is_array($callable)` returns `false`?

Comment: why it is a downside ?

Comment: @HalayemAnis I understand that it is not a clear downside, but I see it like one because I wouldn't expect a callable to be an array. It seem something like an implementation detail that should not be passed around

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is... even though it's a horrid, horrid hack:

```
$foo = new Foo();

function makeCallable($instance, $method)
{
    return function() use ($instance, $method) {
        return $instance->{$method}();//use func_get_args + call_user_func_array to support arguments
    };
}
```

Then you can use:

```
$callable = makeCallable($foo, 'bar');
var_dump(is_array($callable));//false
```

The downside is that:

```
var_dump($callbale instanceof Closure);//true
```

Basically, don't pay any attention to the fact that your callable is also an array, and just use type-hinting throughout your code base:

```
function foobar(callable $action)
{
    return call_user_func($action);
}
```

That ought to work just fine.

On why you feel the current callable array is a downside: I understand why you feel this is not a good thing. There is indeed no need for anyone to know that a particular callable construct is an array, or a string, or an anonymous function (which is actually an instance of the `Closure` class - another implementation detail you might not want to pass around). But it's exactly because callable constructs come in many forms, the `callable` type-hint exists: the code you write that requires a callable needn't care about how that callable entity is implemented, it just needs to know that it can call that piece of information:

```
function handleEvent(callable $action, array $args = null)
{
    if ($args) {
        return call_user_func_array($action, $args);
    }
    return call_user_fun($action);
}
```

No need for me to check if `$action` is a string (like `'strtolower'`, a `Closure` instance or an array) I just *know* I can call it

Comment: that really looks like a hack! Thanks for the answer

Comment: @marcosh: was typing up a quick rant about why you really shouldn't care about what the callable looks like: there are many valid callable/callback constructs in PHP, only one of which is an array

Answer (score 6):

PHP 7.1 finally took a big steep in making callbacks first-class citizens via Closure::fromCallable ([RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/closurefromcallable)).

As described [here](https://blog.shameerc.com/2016/11/php-71-8-new-features-you-need-to-know), you can use it like this:

```
class MyClass
{
  public function getCallback() {
    return Closure::fromCallable([$this, 'callback']);
  }

  public function callback($value) {
    echo $value . PHP_EOL;
  }
}

$callback = (new MyClass)->getCallback();
$callback('Hello World');
```

Using it has some benefits:

- Better error handling - When using Closure::fromCallable, it shows errors in the right place instead of showing it where we are using the callable. This makes debugging a lot easier.
- Wrapping scopes - The above example will work fine even if the callback is a private/protected method of MyClass.
- Performance - This can also improve the performance by avoiding the overhead of checking if the given callable is actually a callable.

Answer (score 5):

Functions and methods are not *first class citizens* in PHP, i.e. they cannot be assigned to variable, do not have a type etc.

`callable` isn't actually a type, `is_callable` as well as the `callable` type hint just checks if something can be *used as a function*. This can be:

- an array `[class, method]` for a static method
- an array `[object, method]` for an instance method
- a string for a function
- a `Closure` instance
- an object that implements the magic method `__invoke()`

As you see, all of these values actually have a different type and just happen to be "callable". There is no such thing as a "pure" callable that does not have another type.